# Git fast-forward merge : why "fast"

Tags: git

Why the fast-forward merge isn't just called a "forward" merge.
Why "Fast" ?

I got that question on a Git training and I can't find the answer. 
Can you help please ?

Comment: The term came from VHS tapes, fast forward was the opposite of rewind. What kind of training are we talking about exactly?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_forward

Comment: @1615903 the term actually came from [audio tapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_recorder), which predate the VHS with several decades.

Comment: First recorded use: 1948 (according to Merriam-Webster) - so before cassette tapes even - [reel-to-reel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reel-to-reel_audio_tape_recording) back in those days.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a reference to fast-forwarding old cassette tapes, I don't think it's a reference to the speed of the process. Just means moving forward in time.

I'm starting to feel old.

Answer (score 0):

A merge always goes forward in the history, whether it is a fast-forward or not. The "fast" does not so much speaks about speed (while it usually also **is** faster than a normal merge).

In terms of speed, a fast-forwards is faster, because the branch pointer is just repointed to a new commit, without the need to create a new merge commit.

But I think the main meaning is lend from older technologies like cassettes and VHS tapes, where you use the fast-forward functionality to go forward on the timeline fastly without modifying anything. A fast-forward merge just moves the current branch pointer forward in the history without modifying anything, meaning without recording a merge commit that combines the histories.